# Unknown on duplicate key update error

Tags: mysql

This is my current statement:

```
INSERT INTO groups (groupName, alias, isDefault, inheritance, permissions)
VALUES ('Admin', 'admin', '0', 'Player', 'test.test') ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE alias = VALUES(alias), isDefault = VALUES(isDefault), 
       inheritance = VALUES(inheritance), permissions = VALUES(permissions);
```

When I execute this, I get a single row that is expected. But when I execute this again, it creates another row. Why does it do that?

Between, I have another column called `id`, and it is auto-incremented.

EDIT: Results of `show create groups`:

```
CREATE TABLE 'groups' (
 'id' int(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 'groupName' varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 'alias' varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 'isDefault' tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 'inheritance' text NOT NULL,
 'permissions' text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: So you execute 2 `INSERT` statements and you have 2 rows inserted. Where is the problem?

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY` - the *`KEY`* part *needs* some key to be duplicate - you have to define some unique index in your table which you want to use as the definition of duplicates. Often the primary key is used for that but it is automatic in your case so you need to define a new one or change the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY` only works when constraint violation. In this cases no constraint will be violated because the primary key is auto incremented column, so you have to add one unique key constraint in your table.